# Some questions about smart card

Tags: smartcard

I use ACS card reader (acr30U) to connect the card.it has two drivers: propriety and PC/SC. i uses both of them. which both, I can connect to card and get ATR, but by any APDU which are inter-industry, I get 6E00.

I am new with smart cards, so here is questions:

My main goal is to program an application on smart card, what are the steps to do that?

I don't know my card have any OS or not? how i can know? 
Can I If I want to install an open source OS on card?

thanks.
Amin

Answer (score 1):

- Stay away from anything proprietary. PC/SC is the right standard.
- When talking about smart card readers, look for CCID compatible (cross-platform)
- Look for an easy start, if you want to write applications *on* the smart card, learn about JavaCard-s. As a general rule about smart cards - the key information is about your *card* (lots of proprietary variations) not the reader (CCID is luckily quite common these days).
  Look for an easy start, use JavaCard-s.
- Also do some homework: [What is the meaning of 6E 00 when I send a command to a SmartCard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609412/what-is-the-meaning-of-6e-00-when-i-send-a-command-to-a-smartcard)

Comment: martin thanks for your reply.

Ok, it seems my question is misunderstood, by "My main goal is to program an application on smart card, what are the steps to do that?" I meant "loading" an application into card. I have no idea about how to do that.

I know that “6E00” means “class not supported”.  But I used inter-industry APDUs such as CLA = 0x00 or 0xa0.